# Problem when I export dae objects

Tags: export

I totally got stuck on a problem: I'm trying to create a landscape for an IOS Game, and everything's fine till I export the object in .dae. Basically, I am able to export everything correct, but the "real" shape of the model is wrong. The object is the same as in Blender, but it is like the shape is related to the original mesh. How can I apply all the subdivision etc I made?

Really thanks!
[image: This is what I got]

Comment: In the .dae export dialog there are options on the bottom left panel where you need to enable "Apply Modifiers" which is off by default.

Comment: I've tried it, both for View and Render, but the problem is still there